# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"xml_document"’

Tags: r

I'm looking to scrape webpages for betting odds, but keep coming across two problems.

I have come across the "html" is deprecated, use xml::read_table which works. Then I come across another issue with ReadHTMLTable, which gives me the error of

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"xml_document"’

```
    library(RCurl)
    library(rvest)
    library(magrittr)
    library(XML)
    library(xml2)


# Append date to output file names:
    IncludeDateTime <- function(str, sep='_', 
    date.format="%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M") {
    stopifnot(is.character(str))
    return(paste(str, format(Sys.time(), date.format), sep=sep))  
    }



    # List of websites for data extraction:
    websiteList <- "http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/",



    betexplorer <- XML::xmlParse(websiteList)
    betexplorerTable <- 
    readHTMLTable(betexplorer,header=T,which=1,stringsAsFactors=F)
    betexplorerTable <- betexplorerTable[2,]
    write.csv(betexplorerTable,
    file=paste(IncludeDateTime("BetexplorerTable"), ".csv"))
```

What I'd like to be able to do is select a table from the given webpage.

Comment: You are conflating two different packages. `XML` has nothing to do with `xml2`. You need to first parse a webpage with `XML::xmlParse` and used that object in `XML::readHTMLTable`.

Comment: @Parfait thanks for the reply. Sorry it's late. I've just finished work. Unfortunately I noticed that the website was https and not http. I tried XML::xmlParse (and have updated my code to make it a bit more streamline)

The error I'm getting now though is : Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/'

Which I'm assuming is due to https?

Comment: Try: `xmlParse(readLines(websiteList))`